# datatables over wcf service

Tags: vb.net, datatables

We would like to pass datatable of information from main application over a web service and finally to the client application.
Does anyone know if there are any issues passing datatables as far as corruption? does datatables have their own checksum or way to check if data has been corrupt?

Comment: I think it would be better and easier to serialize your datatable into json format

Comment: Generally, the objects will be serialized/deserialized when passing from a consuming app into a WCF service so if theres an issue sending the data then the deserialization would fail.

Comment: Ok. do you think that the data inside the data table could ever get corrupt?   we are sending information through a web service to remote clients that have bad connection. just wondering if there was a bad line , could any of the values inside the datatable get corrupted.  apparently this happens sometimes with excel. when you send an excel file sometimes the values in some areas get corrupt for whatever reason. could just be an excel issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize `datatable` to `json`

you may use this function:

```
Public Function SerializeDataTable(dt As DataTable, tableName As String) As String
    Try
        Dim resultMain As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
        Dim index As Integer = 0

        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim result As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

            For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                If column.DataType = GetType(DateTime) AndAlso row(column) <> DBNull.Value Then
                    result.Add(column.ColumnName, DirectCast(row(column), DateTime).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                Else
                    result.Add(column.ColumnName, row(column).ToString())
                End If
            Next

            resultMain.Add(tableName & index.ToString(), result)
            index += 1
        Next

        Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Return js.Serialize(resultMain)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```